# How to convert VB6 encrypting code to c#.net code

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, vb6

I have this VB6 encrypting code created by another developer.

The problem is I'm not familiar with .NET and I need to convert this code to C#. Is there a way help here to convert this code?

```vb
Private mvarKeyString As String 'local copy
Private mvarMainText As String 'local copy
Public Sub Decrypt()
Attribute Decrypt.VB_Description = "Decrypt MainText text based on KeyString key"
   'Shrink
   On Error GoTo Mali

   Dim intC As Integer
   Dim intD As Integer
   Dim nE As Integer
   Dim lngA As Long
   Dim lngB As Long
   Dim lngI As Long
   Dim lngJ As Long
   Dim lngK As Long
   Dim strB As String

   lngA = Len(mvarMainText)
   lngB = lngA - 1 - (lngA - 1) \ 4
   strB = Space(lngB)
   For lngI = 1 To lngB
      lngJ = lngJ + 1
      intC = Asc(Mid(mvarMainText, lngJ, 1)) - 59
      Select Case lngI Mod 3
      Case 1
          lngK = lngK + 4
          If lngK > lngA Then lngK = lngA
          nE = Asc(Mid(mvarMainText, lngK, 1)) - 59
          intD = ((nE \ 16) And 3) * 64
      Case 2
          intD = ((nE \ 4) And 3) * 64
      Case 0
          intD = (nE And 3) * 64
          lngJ = lngJ + 1
      End Select
      Mid(strB, lngI, 1) = Chr(intC Or intD)
   Next lngI

   mvarMainText = strB

   'doXOR
   'Dim intC As Integer
   intC = 0
   Dim intB As Integer
   'Dim lngI As Long
   lngI = 0
   For lngI = 1 To Len(mvarMainText)
       intC = Asc(Mid(mvarMainText, lngI, 1))
       intB = Int(Rnd * 256)
       Mid(mvarMainText, lngI, 1) = Chr(intC Xor intB)
   Next lngI

Mali:
   Select Case Err
   Case 5
      Beep
      MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description, vbCritical
      Exit Sub
   End Select
End Sub
```

I hope you understand what I mean.

I am not able to convert it in Visual Studio because Visual Studio 2013 can't open the project.

Comment: Note that every automated conversion tools do not take advantage of the language intrinsics so if you want a real conversion doing it manually is the only way to get a quality code result.

Comment: is it possible to convert to c#?, the problem is lack of knowlege in vb6

Comment: What kind of encryption standard does your vb6 code use? To be honest, I think it would be easier if you start over, because I don't know if C# will support that kind of encryption. For example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: sorry but theres data already on the db and i need to decrypt the password. thats why i need to convert it to c#

Comment: Ah, so it is for legacy purposes. You could decrypt the data on the database using the vb6 code and encrypt it using C# AES encryption.

Comment: the code if created by former developer here. back on i think 2001. only if im allowed to do that. they want to use the existing . just convert it to c# code

Comment: I would highly advise continuing with vb6 code, since it was released in 1998 and probably no longer secure.

Comment: It doesn't really encrypt - it obfuscates. Notice how it doesn't, in fact, use `mvarKeyString` at all. So there's no key involved here. If you *need* encryption, this isn't it.

Comment: no i just need to convert the code to c#. , sorry  im not good in english

Comment: Don't spam tags. Converting from VB6 to C# has nothing to do with VB.NET.

Comment: Note the usage of `Rnd` in the "Xor" code section. I don't believe that `Rnd` is available in the `Compatibility.VB6` namespace. This means that this code is not convertible to a .Net language (C#, VB.Net or other), and be able to maintain backward compatibility to the existing app and data in the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following.  Has not been tested.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static string mvarKeyString; //local copy
        static string mvarMainText; //local copy
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }

        static void Decrypt()
        {
            string VB_Description = "Decrypt MainText text based on KeyString key";

            int intC = 0;
            int intD = 0;
            int nE = 0;
            long lngA = 0;
            long lngB = 0;
            long lngI = 0;
            long lngJ = 0;
            long lngK = 0;
            string strB = "";
            char[] array;
            try
            {
                lngA = mvarMainText.Length;
                lngB = lngA - 1 - (lngA - 1) / 4;
                strB = new string(' ', (int)lngB);
                for(lngI = 1; lngI <= lngB; lngI++)
                {
                    lngJ = lngJ + 1;
                    intC = (int)mvarMainText.Substring((int)lngJ,1).First() - 59;

                    switch(lngI % 3)
                    {
                        case 0 :
                            intD = (nE & 3) * 64;
                            lngJ = lngJ + 1;
                            break;
                        case 1 :  
                          lngK = lngK + 4;

                          if(lngK > lngA)
                          {
                                lngK = lngA;
                          }
                          nE = (int)mvarMainText.Substring((int)lngK,1).First() - 59;
                          intD = ((nE / 16) & 3) * 64;
                            break;
                        case 2 :
                            intD = ((nE / 4) & 3) * 64;
                            break;
                    }

                    array = strB.ToCharArray();
                    array[(int)lngI] = (char)(intC | intD);
                    strB = String.Join("", array);
                }

                mvarMainText = strB;

                //   'doXOR
                //   'Dim intC As Integer
                intC = 0;
                int intB = 0;

                Random Rnd = new Random();
                for (int i = 1; i <= mvarMainText.Length; i++)
                {
                    intC = (int)mvarMainText.Substring(i, 1).First();
                    intB = Rnd.Next() * 256;

                    array = mvarMainText.ToCharArray();
                    array[lngI] = (char)(intC | intB);
                    mvarMainText = String.Join("", array);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: gives me output of system.char always

Comment: try mvarMaintext = " `J[QPTHbn;"      mvarkeystring = "040079"

Comment: instead of ToString use String.Join("", array)